# Como puedo realizar este paginado con Mysql

Tags: mysql

Bueno mi pregunta es la siguiente. 
Tengo 3 tablas , tabla Producto, TipoProducto,Categoria.
La tabla Producto esta relacionada con la tabla tipoProducto, y la tabla tipoProducto con Categoria.
¿Como puedo paginar una lista de productos por Categoria? 
La logica la tengo , paso id Categoria, trae la lista de tipos que tienen esa Categoria, luego traigo todos los productos que corresponden a esos tipos.

Comment: Puedes añadir las pruebas que hayas hecho para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Si tienes la lógica, que seria lo difícil de sacar, cual es tu pregunta? Supongo que hay diferentes formas de hacerlo, con un JOIN de las 3 tablas podrias sacarlo. producto join tipo producto join categoria where categoria.id = ''; Saludos

Comment: de lo que te entiendo las relaciones en las tablas las tienes declaradas ahora te propongo es lo siguiente: 1. Con el select que debe contener las tres tablas, crear una vista, con esto en tu lenguaje será más sencillo de extraer la consulta. 2. Para mostrarla en una pagina debes hacer ciertos calculos: ¿Cuántos registros tiene la consulta en forma general?, ¿Cuantos registros quires que muestre?, con esto podrás calcular el número de paginas tiene tu consulta. 3. Al realizar la busqueda se recomienda que debes tener en cuenta que podrias búscar por varios criterios debes preparar un select qu

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Cristian! te doy la bienvenida,  es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!.